# is it possible to find X and Y such that E[X] is positive, Y is positive and E[XY] is strictly negative?

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

If $X$ is an integrable real random variables such that $E[X] \ge 0$ and $Y$ is a positive integrable random variable is it possible that E[XY]<0 ?

Comment: Try with X and Y each taking two values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: 
$$
X(t) = 2  \text{ for $0 \le t \le 1$ } \\
X(t) = -1 \text{ for $-1 \le t < 0$ } \\
X(t) = 0 \text{ elsewhere,}
$$
while
$$
Y(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2} \text{ for $t < 0$ } \\
Y(t) = .00001 \frac{1}{1+t^2} \text{ for $t \ge 0$ } \\
$$

Comment: Cool. I found another counterexample with $X \in \{-1,1\}$ and $Y \in \{a,b\}$. One can cook the joint distribution such that all the inequalities are matched. Nice exercise, anyway... Thanks John.

Comment: For which probability measure on the real line?

Comment: Good point, Did. Answer: for any symmetric measure (i.e., $p(x) = p(-x)$) that's nonzero on the interval $[-1, 1]$. For instance, this example works with $p(x) = 1/4, \text{ for $-2 \le x \le 2$ }$, and $0$ for all other $x$.